# New Years Eve Clock won't redirect at midnight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a clock on a web page that will switch to another web page at midnight using `window.location.replace`.

The clock works but when I add `oneSecondFunction`, the `if` statement in particular, my clock disappears.

Here's the clock:

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();

  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  }
  return i;
}
```

... and here's the location replace that doesn't work AND breaks my clock:

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 1000);
});

function oneSecondFunction() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();

  if (h == 0) {
    window.location.replace("midnight.html");
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you replace the location every time the page is entered?

Comment: can you check the path of your midnight.html...if . or / is not added it will replace with the last segment,so it might be'/midnight.html' or './midnight.html' according to where your file is..

Comment: Thanks for your help friends. Teemu, I thought my code would only run the window.location.replace when h = 0 (start of the new year). But I could be mistaken?

Comment: I tried . and ./ before midnight.html. No luck. Thanks for trying BittuS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my demo. The example will wait until the desired date will occur then it will trigger a callback. You can find the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bj859yg0/) to adjust the `newYear` date.

```js
function waitForNewYear(cb) {

  if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
    cb = function() {};
  }

  var present = new Date(); // current time

  //let newYear = new Date(2019, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); // <- Real New Years Eve date

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
  let newYear = new Date(2018, 11, 28, 17, 0, 0); // <- Use this constructor to pass a date that works on IE

  var dateDiff = newYear - present;

  var remainingDays = Math.floor(dateDiff / 86400000);
  var remainingHours = Math.floor(dateDiff / 3600000 % 24);
  var remainingMinutes = Math.floor(dateDiff / 60000 % 60);
  var remainingSeconds = Math.floor(dateDiff / 1000 % 60);

  remainingDays = remainingDays < 10 ? '0' + remainingDays : remainingDays;
  remainingHours = remainingHours < 10 ? '0' + remainingHours : remainingHours;
  remainingMinutes = remainingMinutes < 10 ? '0' + remainingMinutes : remainingMinutes;
  remainingSeconds = remainingSeconds < 10 ? '0' + remainingSeconds : remainingSeconds;

  var elem = document.getElementById('txt');

  if (dateDiff <= 0) {

    elem.innerHTML = '00 00:00:00';

    cb();

  } else {

    var elem = document.getElementById('txt');
    elem.innerHTML = remainingDays + ' ' + (parseInt(remainingDays) === 1 ? 'day ' : 'days ') + remainingHours + ':' + remainingMinutes + ':' + remainingSeconds;

    var ct = setTimeout(function() {
      clearTimeout(ct);
      waitForNewYear(cb);
    }, 1000);

  }

}

waitForNewYear(function() {

  console.log('Happy New Year !');

  //window.location.replace("midnight.html");

});
```

```css
#txt {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="txt">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. However, I need to make this work on an offline (no external internet access) network using Internet Explorer 11. So that means I can't use any libraries like JQuerry, right. It has to be straight up javascript and HTML5

Comment: It doesn’t require any external library ... just copy/paste it

Comment: Oh! I tried that and the clock is still missing. I'll futz with it for a while and see if I missing something obvious. I did get one error when I used the developer tools in chrome.

Comment: ncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at waitForNewYear (ClockPageNYE.html:77)
    at ClockPageNYE.html:88
waitForNewYear @ ClockPageNYE.html:77
(anonymous) @ ClockPageNYE.html:88

Comment: @user2399541 well you need `<div id="txt"></div>` , check the function, i have there `document.getElementById('txt')` , you can adjust it however you like

Comment: Oh, yes of course :) Perhaps I should have given the whole webpage at the start.

Comment: I'll try to make the page on fiddle

Comment: I figured out two mistakes I made and got the page/code to work in chrome. I very happy in that moment :) I do really appreciate your help darklighcode.

Comment: ...but Internet Explorer 11 won't do it

Comment: @user2399541 I have updated the function to work on IE11 too. If you found my solution helpful please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: You did it! Thank you so much.FYI, I'm going to beg IT where I work to replace IE as our default browser on all of our display players.

Comment: I did make one change. Moving window.location.replace("midnight.html"); to line 69 so, instead of showing 0:00:00:00 the page reloads right away to midnight.html. Should I make that change in the accepted answer above?

Comment: @user2399541 Yes, you can do that. You can adjust the function as you see fit.